# Retrieve all data from backend with angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Here is the problem :

I have a list of docs in my database that i retrieve with my server.
My angular applications as to retrieve the entire list of docs. My list of docs is available with an offset.
For example :
I call my server with offset 0 and retrieve the first docs from 0 to 600 then i call with offset 600 that retrieve from 601 to 1200 etc...  until I get a 404 by my server which means the end.

I want to do that with angular, I tried using 'while' like that :

```
    let done = false;
    let offset = 0;
    const docList = [];
    while(!done) {
       this.docService.retrieveDoc(url, offset).subscribe(result => {
          docList.push(result);
          offset = doclist.length;
       }, err => {
          done = true;
       });
    }
```

But thats not working, the while don't wait for the server respond and just launch the http request infinitly

Do you guys have an idea ? :)

Thx for youre help !

Comment: Please define "Not Working"

Comment: `docList` and  `doclist` are not cased the same.

Comment: I change the doclist => docList ; the issue here is the while don't wait for the subscribe to respond and keep launching request infinitly

Comment: You most likely want to use async/await in the loop instead of a subscription, as it will loop as fast as it can without waiting.

Comment: I suggest having a look at [this](https://medium.com/@teebszet/recurse-with-rxjs-observables-and-switchmap-de5942532ea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a loop, you should do `async/await`, as the loop will run as fast as it can. Since subscribe completes almost instantly, it will call the `while` again and this will repeat hundreds of times before the subscription is finally executed. Using an `await` in the loop will pause the loop until the action has completed then continue on.

To keep what you have, you would do something like this:

```js
public async doSomething() {
    let done = false;
    let offset = 0;
    const docList = [];
    while(!done) {
      try {
        const result = await this.docService.retrieveDoc(url, offset).pipe(first()).toPromise();
        docList.push(result);
        offset = doclist.length;
      } catch(e) {
        done = true;
      }
    }
}
```

As mentioned, you could also take a recursive approach removing the loop altogether.

```js
private docList = [];

public doSomething(url: string) {
    this.docService.retrieveDoc(url, docList.length).subscribe(result => {
        this.docList.push(result);
        doSomething(url);
    });
}
```

Comment: is `async/await` a good approach ? I think a recursive solution is much better

Comment: Both ways would work. Just depends on which approach the user wants to take.

Comment: I think it is always good to avoid async/await on front end, you don't want an api call taking some 500ms to block your event loop

Comment: It Works ! I use the second way, with the recursive and it works perfectly, thx :)